# How to get request body from custom authorizer in pac4j in play framework

Tags: playframework, pac4j

I am trying to implement a custom **authorizer** in my web application using play framework with pac4j. My custom authorizer is getting called but I am not able to access request payload as string using WebContext's `getRequestContent()` method. It is coming as null. I am able to access request headers properly.

My custom authorizer

```
package v2;

import org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.ProfileAuthorizer;
import org.pac4j.core.context.WebContext;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;
import org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile;
import org.pac4j.play.PlayWebContext;

import java.util.List;

public class OPAAuthorizer extends ProfileAuthorizer {
    @Override
    public boolean isAuthorized(WebContext context, SessionStore sessionStore, List<UserProfile> profiles) {
        System.out.println(context.getRequestHeader("Authorization"));
        System.out.println(context.getRequestContent());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isProfileAuthorized(WebContext context, SessionStore sessionStore, UserProfile profile) {
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, there was a bug on the *getRequestContent()* method which could only be called once. It should be fixed in the latest pac4j versions.
If so, please put a breakpoint in this method to see if it is called many times for the same `PlayWebContext` object.